# rails summing column values of rows with similar attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Sites table that has columns name, and time. The name does not have to be unique. So for example I may have the entries 'hi.com, 5', 'hi.com, 10', 'bye.com, 4'.
I would like to sum up all the unique sites so that i get 'hi.com, 15' and 'bye.com, 4' for plotting purposes. How can I do that?
(For some reference I was looking at http://railscasts.com/episodes/223-charts but I couldn't get the following (translated to my table) to work

```
def self.total_on(date) 
  where("date(purchased_at) = ?", date).sum(:total_price) 
end
```

nor do I really understand the syntax of the '`where("date(purchased_at) = ?", date)`' part.

Thanks for helping a rails newbie!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

let's say you have a model called *Site*, with columns *name* and *time*

to do what you want, just say something like

```
sites = Site.sum(:time, :group => 'name')
```

this will result a hash like

```
{"bye.com"=>4, "hi.com"=>15}
```

then, you can do whatever you want with the hash

Comment: is there a quick way to get just ['bye.com', 'hi.com'] and/or [4, 15] from the resulting hash?

Comment: ok, thanks. this works great in my app but I realized I'd still like to keep another column's information. so Sites has a column named 'type', but of course when i do the above, the type column disappears.  each unique 'name' will have the same 'type' if that helps...is there any way to have store some kind of second value that is the 'type'? or I was thinking I could go through the Sites table again and pull all the unique names and their types, but that seems too repetitive. thanks!

Comment: this is kind of a new question. i'm not sure you can do that easy and nice like above (don't know a nice and clean way to do it). by the way, don't ever name a column "type", you'll get into trouble.

Comment: ok, thanks. yeah it's not really called type :) what's bad about it other than nondescriptive?